# How to list all instance variables?

Tags: php

Is there a way to list all of an instance's variables, ideally in an array or an associative array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you mean something like

```
var_dump($obj);
```

this will output all the variables used by an object or instance of an object.

you can also use

```
debug_backtrace();
```

this will output somewhat the same information as a `var_dump` but also give you extra information about what file, classes, and methods were called

Comment: Ah, I've used that for debugging, but I didn't think of using it for this.  What is the order used to list the variables?  Same order they're listed in the code?

Comment: the variables are listed in the order they are accessed. When you do a print_r from a `debug_backtrace` you can see the associative array of variables and then call them from that. `$bt = debug_backtrace(); echo $bt[0]['class'];` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Built in [get_defined_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) might be what you want. Works for global scope and functions. Methods and classes are slightly less straight forward and require [Reflections](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways:

- get_object_vars gives all instance vars that are visible to the calling scope
- the reflection class can give and filter all instance vars from a class